# WxPython ToolBar Tool reference from mouse event

Tags: wxpython, toolbar

My application dynamically creates toolbar tools, thus there is only one mouse event handler assigned to any tool the user might mouse click on.  Is there a way to get either a reference index to the tool, or the object of the tool, that the user clicked on?

The toolbar is created like this,

```
self.m_toolBar = wx.ToolBar( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TB_HORIZONTAL )
self.m_toolBar.Bind( wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onToolBar )
```

New tools are added like this,

```
self.m_toolBar.AddTool(wx.NewId(), "foo", wx.Bitmap(path), "bar")
```

The event handler, onToolBar, I can get the original toolbar object, self.m_toolBar,

```
event.GetEventObject()
```

but I can't find any reference to the actual tool that the user selected.  The event.GetId() always returns the ID of wx.ToolBar, not the ToolBarBase object that I seek.

Options,

1) I did notice that I can get the (x,y) position of the mouse, and I could calculate which tool (index) was pressed based on the size of the tool icons, etc, but that just doesn't feel like the right way to do this.
2) I think I could create multiple wx.ToolBar objects and put only one tool in each, thus the event.GetId() would relate directly to the tool being selected.

3) Another option I tried is to,

```
    obj = self.m_toolBar.AddTool(wx.NewId(), status_tip, wx.Bitmap(path), tooltip)
    obj.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onToolBarObj)
```

But 'ToolBarToolBase' object has no attribute 'Bind'

But there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the core issue was not using the right bind method for the added tool, instead of,

```
obj = self.m_toolBar.AddTool(wx.NewId(), status_tip, wx.Bitmap(path), tooltip)
obj.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onToolBarObj)
```

Should have been,

```
obj = self.m_toolBar.AddTool(wx.NewId(), status_tip, wx.Bitmap(path), tooltip)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onToolBarObj, obj)
```

Comment: Toolbar and menubar events are bound against the frame object in most cases, which is what the `self` refers to here, I assume.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the ToolBarBase object as so:

```
obj = self.m_toolBar.AddTool(wx.NewId(), status_tip, wx.Bitmap(path), tooltip)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onToolBarObj, obj)

def onToolBarObj(self, event)
pid = event.GetId()
tool = event.GetEventObject().FindById(pid)
```

After you have 'tool' you can do just about do anything you want to the toolbar tool.